# How to distribute sql results over column x?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I have a table of houses.

```
City | Address | Price | NewRelease
Auckland, 18 Queen St, 1000000, true
Auckland, 21 Queen St, 1100000, false
Auckland, 23 Queen St, 1150000, false
Wellington, 23 Cuba St, 850000, false
.....
```

What I want to do is be able to query that list and return a list of x houses that are in a particular city AND I want the list to be as evenly balanced as possible between NewReleases, so theres roughly half true and half false. The function needs to be able to accept an input as to how many houses from a region to return. Something like houses_in_region(amount)

Sometimes there might not be enough of each to get a 50/50 split then its most important that the overall right number is just returned. For example if you ask for 10 houses in Wellington but there are only 12 houses in wellington in the db and all of them are NewRelease=false then it should just return 10 of those. However if you ask the same in Auckland where there might be 1000, then you should return 10 houses with 5 of them being NewRelease and 5 that are not.

Is this possible with sql?

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
DECLARE @i int = 6, -- How many rows we want to show
        @s int  --  This will determine what will be inserted first 

DECLARE @Results TABLE ( --Result table
    City nvarchar(100), 
    [Address] nvarchar(100), 
    [Price] int,
    [NewRelease] bit
)

SELECT @s = CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN NewRelease = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > SUM(CASE WHEN NewRelease = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM YourTable

INSERT INTO @Results  -- Insert half of needed rows
SELECT TOP (@i/2) *
FROM YourTable 
WHERE NewRelease = @s

SELECT @i = @i-COUNT(*)  --Re-count how many rows we need more
FROM @Results

INSERT INTO @Results --Insert another part of rows
SELECT TOP (@i) *
FROM YourTable 
WHERE NewRelease != @s

SELECT *  --show data selected
FROM @Results
ORDER BY NewRelease DESC
```